# LibGDX: How to make the ScrollPane scroll down automatically?

Tags: libgdx, scrollpane

What I've tried:

```
scrollPane.setScrollPercentY(100);
```

and

```
scrollPane.setScrollY(1);
```

or

`scrollPane.setScrollY(0);`

But it only scrolls to the top, not to the bottom.

Comment: Try setting the scroll percent to 0 to go to the bottom, or increment/decrement it every frame to slowly change it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, it worked that way:

```
scrollPane.scrollTo(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 9):

For me, this worked instead:

```
scrollPane.layout();
scrollPane.scrollTo(0, 0, 0, 0);
```